# small classes how to pass by value and register

Tags: c++

I need to use small classes formed essentially from just an integer "handle" and be able to treat that as a class in order to be able to attach methods to it.
At the same time I want also to avoid to pass from one function to the other just the address of the handle ( the "this" pointer) because doing so means that in order to read a handle that should just be there I would need to read a memory location to have it.

So I need essentially to have the "handle" passed by value eventually in registers ( depending on calling convention ).

Some clarifying code is:

```
struct F{
int aa,bb,cc;};

F A[0x100];

struct handle{
int hhh;
void elaborateHandle(){ ... operations ;}
};

int main(){
  handle h;h.hhh=3;
  h.elaborateHandle();
// I need that call to pass on the stack essentially the number 3 and not the address of where the number 3 was saved on the stack.
}
```

Comment: `elaborateHandle` should be `const` because changing `hhh` would require the address which you are trying to avoid. Also what are `struct F` and the array `A` for? They are not used in you code.

Comment: And you shouldn't worry is value passed in register or not, the compiler will use the best fitting way.

Comment: And define a constructor from `int` so to facilite initialisation: `handle h(3);`

Comment: You could make `elaborateHandle` a free function that takes an `F` as argument by-value. You can make it a `friend` of `F` if you decide later to make the three `int` members `private`.

Comment: @nwp Yes you are right it must be const in order to be able to avoid the address ( as the object is passed by reference to the method ).

Comment: @5gon12eder Whtat I try to do is exactly to have the efficiency of a free function but trying to fit it in the frame of methods. The previous code I try to "upgrade" to a more object like version was based only on free functions with "handles" passes as integers.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Maybe reading [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) -- if you haven't already -- makes you feel more comfortably with the free function approach. Since having passed a `this` pointer is the very nature of a member function, I don't think there is a way to avoid it. Also, in my previous comment `F` should be replaced by `handle` and three by one of course; sorry for that.

Comment: @5gon12eder the "this" link was very interesting and informative.

Comment: Having found I was taking a ~10% performance hit for _assuming_ pass-by-value was using register passing, investigation revealed that the compiler _can_ pass a class in a register, but various things block it (in my case a spurious copy constructor).  Since the calling convention has to be agreed across compilation units, the rules must be well defined about what makes the difference, but I do not know where to look.  This question needs a good answer, because the performance implication can be non-negligible and because the answer must actually be defined somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you shouldn't think about it, because here you are having a very very small performance lose, dereferencing one pointer is a cheap operation.

If you use optimizing compiler, there is a chance, that your method call will be inlined inside caller func.

Anyways, if you trying to optimize your performance, you should search in other place.

But if you really thinking that it causes troubles there is a way:
Declare the function outside your class (not as member), and if you want to access private data declare it as friend.

Comment: Normaly I shouldn't but trying to make an interpreter, and being each primitive executed by an access to the handle, it makes sense to bother about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, print the assembly language of the code that calls your function and the first part of your function.

The assembly language will show how the registers are used.  Normally, compilers try to make best use of registers when passing values to functions.

## To help the compiler better use registers:

### Limit parameter quantities in functions.

The compiler reserves a limited quantity of registers for passing to functions.  The more parameters a function has, the less probability that all parameters will be in registers.

Also, the compiler may need to save registers before calling a function in order to pass more parameters to the function.

### Pass values that fit inside registers.

If the compiler can't fit a data type in one register, it may use two registers (such as passing 64 bit values on a 32-bit processor).

If the compiler can't fit the data type in two registers, it may push the data on the stack rather than passing by register.  This means that the receiving function will have to copy the values from the stack.

Pass large items by reference or pointer.  On most platforms, the compiler can store a pointer into a register and pass the register to the receiving function.  A lot faster that pushing and popping values with a stack.  Also, compilers may use pointers to implement references.

### Suggest to the compiler to place values in registers.

Although the `register` keyword may not be available in more recent language versions, using the `register` keyword with variables suggests to the compiler that you would like to have the variable in a register.  It is only a suggestion and the compiler can ignore it and you.

Define variables as close to their point of usage.  This allows the compiler to allocate registers when needed rather than reserving them for a while.

Create scope blocks.  Using `{` and `}` to create new scope blocks will help the compiler allocate and deallocate registers that are used only in a limited area.  So if variables are only used in a limited area in a function, place that area in a new scope block.  You can even tag those local variable with the `register` keyword.

### Compile with high optimization levels.

Set your compiler's optimization levels high, then check the assembly language.

The compiler may use memory for variable storage when optimization is at the lowest setting (debugging).  At higher optimization levels, the compiler starts using registers more effectively.

Remember, print the assembly language of the functions and the calling code before and after playing with optimization levels.

Comment: >  variables as close to their point of usage ..( and scope blocks), optimizing compiler automatically deletes redundant assignments, destructs objects, which will not been used later.

Answer (score 0):

Using the g++ compiler on the x86 platform, I found that the flag "-freg-struct-return" has a different effect that described in the documentation. According to my tests, that flag, obliges the compiler to pass structures by value ( I didn't checked it but it will be probably be valid when structures have a size smaller than a specific size -- I checked up to 64 bits and it works compiling using -m32 ).
Differently from what the documentation says, structs aren't passed in registers, unless a register passing convention in used.

That behaviour is valid also for declared or compiler recognized const methods of structures ( or classes ).
So if a method doesn't change the structure, than the structure is passed by value ( in stack allocated space or in registers depending e.g. on defining a function using the  `__attributes__ (( regparam(3) ))` .
Instead as it should be, if a structure is modified by a method, than the address is passed to the method instead of the value of the struct ( as it should be ).

The documentation of that flag is misleading because it says: "Return struct and union values in registers when possible. This is more efficient for small structures than -fpcc-struct-return.
If you specify neither -fpcc-struct-return nor -freg-struct-return, GCC defaults to whichever convention is standard for the target. If there is no standard convention, GCC defaults to -fpcc-struct-return, except on targets where GCC is the principal compiler. In those cases, we can choose the standard, and we chose the more efficient register return alternative."

The testing code I used is bellow, the effects may be seen by seeing what the disassemler shows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int aa[100];

struct Token{
    short int ind; short int ind1; short int ind2;
    int v() const{return aa[ind];}
    __attribute((noinline)) void setind(int i){ind=i;}
    __attribute((noinline)) int tok() {return ind;}
};

__attribute__ ((noinline)) void showIt(Token t){
    t.ind+=t.ind;
    a+=t.ind;
    t.ind=8;
}

Token t0 = {.ind=15};
Token t1 = {.ind=99};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t0.setind(10);
    int x=19;
    x=t0.tok();

    showIt(t0);
    t1.setind(20+x);
    showIt(t1);
    printf("%i\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```